Gradio progress Bar displays two times
I am working on my Gradio app in which i am using two Gradio components gr.HTML and gr.File . I have one button which calls one function through .click() method.
In function i have used progress bar and in output i am taking value for gr.HTML and gr.File.
But during the process it displays two progress bars but i want only one progress bar.
Here is my code snippet
        process_btn = gr.Button("Create Note")
        
        status = gr.HTML(label="Status")
        download = gr.File(label="Download Your Note",interactive=False)

    def update_download_link(file_path):
        return gr.File.update(value=file_path, visible=True)

    process_btn.click(
        fn=process,
        inputs=[agree, doc_type, audio, file, session_state],
        outputs=[status, download]
    )



This is process function which Do some work and gives status and file name in output

    def process(agreement, document_type, microphone_input: np.ndarray, transcript_files,     session_state: dict, progress=gr.Progress()):


